# not equal condition does not work in javascript

Tags: javascript, conditional-statements

Does anybody have an idea why the following condition does not work in javascript?

```
if ($(this).is(':checked') && this.name != 'AllgS') {
    $('#'+this.name+'colors').show('slow');
} 
else {
    $('#'+this.name+'colors').hide('slow');
}
```

The second condition is not excepted, but I don't get an error message.
Using

```
if ($(this).is(':checked') && this.name == 'AllgS') {
    $('#'+this.name+'colors').show('slow');
} 
else {
    $('#'+this.name+'colors').hide('slow');
}
```

works...

EDIT: 
the whole function is

```
$('.Kennzahl').click(function(){
        if ($(this).is(':checked') && this.name != 'AllgS') {$('#'+this.name+'colors').show('slow');} else {$('#'+this.name+'colors').hide('slow');}
        if ($(this).is(':checked') && this.name == 'AllgS') {$('#'+this.name+'colors').show('slow');} 
        else {
            if ($('#AllgS').prop('checked') == false && $('#BerufS').prop('checked') == false)
            $('#'+this.name+'colors').hide('slow');
            else {}
        }

    });
```

Comment: `this` is a checkbox? can you show the markup of this checkbox?

Comment: How are you getting `this`? Is it handled with `jQuery`? Have you checked console for any errors/messages. I would try  printing values of `$(this).is(":checked")` and `this.name` to start with.

Comment: [Your code works](https://jsfiddle.net/q4rsg2hy/). Could you be facing a logic error in that you're not testing what you think you are testing? Can you describe what you expect to happen when the code is executed?

Comment: try to add brackets to second part in your condition like this `($(this).is(':checked') && (this.name !== 'AllgS')){}`

Comment: @whois42: What difference would that make?

Comment: @TheVillageIdiot, you are right, testing other functions with the condition in console.log() works, so the problem should be elsewhere

Answer (score 0):

tye to put this.name=="xx" in a brace because whatever you wrote is not valid condition test

```
  if ($(this).is(':checked') && (this.name == 'AllgS')) {
$('#'+this.name+'colors').show('slow');
  } 
 else {
  $('#'+this.name+'colors').hide('slow');
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, your code works after little bit of modification. Check this <kbd>[fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/q4rsg2hy/2/)</kbd>.

Moreover if you pay attention to your indentation, it will be easier to figure out errors. Without full markup and any other idea, I tried to reproduce behaviour from the code you have in your question. Following code shows the `div` with id *AllgS* if corresponding checkbox is checked.

```
$('.Kennzahl').click(function(){
    $("#a").html($(this).is(":checked")+"  :   "+this.name);
    if ($(this).is(':checked') && this.name != 'AllgS') {
        $('#'+this.name+'colors').show('slow');
    } else {
        $('#'+this.name+'colors').hide('slow');
    }
    if ($(this).is(':checked') && this.name == 'AllgS') {
        $('#'+this.name+'colors').show('slow');
    } 
    else if (!$('#AllgS').prop('checked') && !$('#BerufS').prop('checked')){
        $('#'+this.name+'colors').hide('slow');
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the fiddle and sorry that I couldn't make it myself... The point was that two checkboxes should be able to fire the same process, and should be only deactivated when both of them are unchecked. Now I solved it on another way, but I still do not understand why it didn't work. At the end it is probably another problem as the not equal condition...